# Related to Principle of Duality (Boolean Algebra)

Tags: boolean-expression

When we write:

A(B+C) = AB + AC

doesn't the principle of duality tells us that all 0s and 1s should be complement of each other and the dot and + operator is interchanged?

Then: won't

A' + (B'C') = (A'+B') (A'+C')

be the correct way of writing its duality? 
My textbook writes the same instead without the complement signs. Why is it so?

EDIT:
It could be that A and B were referring to general binary variables.However, judging by the way that they said 0 . 0 = 0 has its dual as 1+1=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because every single term is complemented, it’s equivalent (up to isomorphism) to the expression where none of the terms is complemented. They’ve all flipped identically relative to each other, so the truth table doesn’t change for that expression.

Comment: I got it! Thanks